# Concatenated strings in sqlDataReader query string introduce spurious 'N' character

Tags: sql, .net, sqldatareader

I am using a `SqlDataReader` in .net 4.0

```
Dim wSQL = "Select (LastName + N',b' + FistName) as CustomerName from Customers"
Dim wSQLDataReader as SQLDataReader = wSQLConnection.ExecuteReader(wSQL)
```

[I am using the letter `b` to denote a space character.]

I am getting results like `'SmithN,bJohn'`

I get the same result if I omit the N qualifier from within the wSQL string.

If the `wSQL` string is changed to

```
"Select (LastName + N',bb' + FistName) as CustomerName from Customers"
```

(with two spaces following the comma).

I get result `'Smith,bbJohn'` with the two spaces (of course) but the `N` has disappeared.

Is this a known .Net bug? Is there a known work around to avoid the extra space?

Both the above `select` statements run fine in SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: try to use `"Select CONCAT(LastName, N', ', FistName) as CustomerName from Customers"`

Comment: What is wSQLConnection? SqlCommand has an ExecuteReader function, not SqlConnection (to my knowledge).

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the + sign before N..you may also need a comma after LastName.. Like this:

```
Dim wSQL = "Select (LastName N',b' + FistName) as CustomerName from Customers"
Dim wSQLDataReader as SQLDataReader = wSQLConnection.ExecuteReader(wSQL)
```

I have a query that is similar (but more complex) maybe it will help you it is:

```
SELECT  
'All Users' as QuestionOption,
Stuff( (SELECT N'; ' + email FROM users where email>='  ' FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE) 
.value('text()[1]','nvarchar(max)'),1,2,N'') as QuestionOptionValue
```

It may look something like:

```
 Dim wSQL = "Select 'CustomerName' as CustomerName, Stuff( (SELECT LastName N', ' +     FirstName FROM CustomerName FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('text()[1]','nvarchar(max)'),1,2,N'') as Customer_Full_Name
```